# What am i doing wrong that my CSS external style sheet is not working?

Tags: html, css

I am working with my first CSS assignment and i need to use and EXTERNAL css file. Everything is saved on my hard drive. I my HTML is not picking up my stylesheet and i have no clue what im doing wrong.

Code:
[image: CSS/HTML Code]

Browser console:
[image]

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested? [Screenshots of code are discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4642212). Still, it looks like a simple typo: your file is called `Styles.css`, yet you link to a file called `stylesheet.css`.

Comment: Good catch, I made the correction. Still not picking it up. I added the f12 error.

Answer (score 0):

Well the better way to ask would be to to post the code in the question itself, but no worries! As much as I can see, there are 2 errors in the code:

1. You have used the `link` tag within the `style` tag. Everything within the `style` tag is read as CSS and not HTML. So the `link` tag is considered as invalid CSS. **Solution:** remove the `style` tag.
2. Your css file is `styles.css` and you have linked `stylesheet.css`. **Solution:** Change the name of the linked file to `styles.css`.

So, the code should be:

```
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\users\dilli\CTS 110\Project 1\CSS\styles.css">
</head>
```

Comment: that was exactly right. thank you very very much1

Comment: Glad I could help